# How to do something like UPDATE DELAYED in MySQL

Tags: mysql, update

I have an averages table that should keep track of an average value over time.  I don't want to have a row for each value, just a single row that continuously updates the average.  What I've come up with is this:

```
set @value=4;
set @name="myAverageValue";
UPDATE `timing` SET
  `max` = greatest(`max`,@value),
  `average` = `average` + ((@value - `average`) / (`count` + 1)),
  `count` = `count` + 1
WHERE `name` = @name
```

Many clients may be doing this at the same time, and I don't want there to be any locking issues.  I don't care what order the updates are run in, since in the end it will all end up the same.  I just want to have a query that sends the UPDATE to the database, and it will process it eventually, similar to an `INSERT DELAYED`.  Does `UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY` do this, or does that cause the client to wait until it is available?

Comment: Your example uses static variables, but where do these things that you're averaging actually come from?  Are you averaging values from another table?

Comment: The values com from a PHP script.

Comment: You should be storing "sum" and "count" - not the "average" - and calculate it ("sum"/"count"), when you need it. The way you are doing it now, you will have (subtle or big) calculation errors in the "average" values.

Comment: I don't really care that much about calculation errors, I'm just looking for a ballpark value.

Answer (score 2):

While there is no such command as `UPDATE DELAYED`, you can create this mechanism in a rather strange way. Please follow my rather crazy train of thought...

**SCENARIO** : Let's say you have just a single DB Server called M1

- You want to fire UPDATEs at a single table called `mydb.timing`
- You don't want UPDATEs to log jam the table

**SOLUTION** : Serialize UPDATEs

**MECHANISM** : Would you believe MySQL Replication ?

That's right, I said MySQL Replication.

You are probably saying right now

> How in the world would having a Slave create UPDATE DELAYED ?

Here is how you do it:

STEP 01 : Using another DB Server (call it M2), create a MySQL Instance with binary logging enabled.

STEP 02 : mysqldump all user databases with no data, just structures (called it MySQLSchema.sql)

STEP 03 : Edit MySQLSchema.sql, change all `ENGINE=MyISAM` into `ENGINE=BLACKHOLE`

STEP 04 : Edit MySQLSchema.sql, change all `ENGINE=InnoDB` into `ENGINE=BLACKHOLE`

STEP 05 : Run `source MySQLSchema.sql` on M2.

STEP 06 : Run `RESET MASTER;` on M2

STEP 07 : Add `replicate-do-table=mydb.timing` to `/etc/my.cnf` on M1

STEP 08 : `service mysql restart` on M1

STEP 09 : Setup replication from M2 to M1

STEP 10 : In your application, fire your code

```
set @value=4;
set @name="myAverageValue";
UPDATE `mydb.timing` SET
  `max` = greatest(`max`,@value),
  `average` = `average` + ((@value - `average`) / (`count` + 1)),
  `count` = `count` + 1
WHERE `name` = @name
```

only at M2

That's it. No locking can ever happen on M2 since `mydb.timing` on M2 uses the [**BLACKHOLE Storage Engine (a.k.a /dev/null Storage Engine)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html). Having MySQL Replication from M2 to M1 forms a queue that serializes UPDATEs. The delay appears in the form of MySQL Replication's asynchronous operation. Replication lag (in this instance only) is totally acceptable since you are looking for `UPDATE DELAYED`.

Give it a Try !!!

## CAVEAT

This turns MySQL Replication upside down because the production server becomes a Slave to a BlackHole Server. With this strange topology, you can also implement `DELETE DELAYED`.

Make sure you include this option

```
[mysqld]
expire-logs-days=1
```

on M2. Otherwise, lots of UPDATEs makes for lots of binlogs

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that that will do what you want because it will be very dependent on SELECT timing. Even if it waits until their are no selects pending (which it will only do for some table types, eg MyISAM, and not InnoDB, which you are probably using), the update could still take time, which would block new SELECTS. So you would still run into locking errors.

I don't believe the UPDATE returns until it actually runs.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: I don't care considerably about SELECTs.  There aren't really many SELECTs on this table at all.  I'm essentially just using this as a way to update the average atomically.

Comment: If you don't care about SELECTs then UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY doesn't buy you anything. It sounds like what you really want is a lightweight messaging endpoint. How important is the data? If you can afford a little potential loss you could use a memory table and just periodically sync to a disk table.

Comment: What I'm worried about is if a hundred clients are trying to run the query at the same time, will 99 of them have to wait?  Or can the client simply tell the server that this query needs to be run at some point?

Comment: So what if they wait a few milliseconds? If your table is using InnoDB and the primary key is `name`, the lockings will happen only for clients that want to update the same row.